# How to allow file creation with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, java-6

I am using a *JFileChooser* to allow the user to select a file and save the current game to it. The problem is that it allows just file selection, and it does not let create a file on the fly and save the game on it. Without creating a custom class, is there a way to allow this behavior in *JFileChooser*? I am using the file chooser to just select files, this is the code that I've written:

```
JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
chooser.setDialogTitle("Save the current game");
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Poker","Poker"));
int value= chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
if(value== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    File file= chooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Selected file " + file);
    BufferedWriter writer= null;
    try
    {
        writer= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(APP_ID);
        writer.write(tax);
        writer.write(money);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to write file: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(writer!= null)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to close file: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the file chooser does not do I/O.

Comment: Is there another class that would allow that?

Comment: What do you mean by `saving the game`? If you want to save the state of the game then you need to write your own API. Maybe use a Properties file to save the state of your variables.

Comment: Now the problem is about how choosing the file and possibly create it. Don't pay attention to that detail, it's irrelevant, it will just be a serializable class.